# NotSupportedException while using GetStreamAsync to get RSS

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, rss, notsupportedexception

I'm writing an RSS reader in Visual Studio 2015 Community. My project is in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight.

I have followed the instructions found on [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RKNr0Y2AvY).

The problem is, when the project is about to be tested on the emulator, a `NotSupportedException` is thrown at the following piece of code:

```
public async void LoadRss(string url) {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Rss));
        this.Rss = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as Rss; //THE CURSOR POINTS HERE
        IsLoaded = true;
    }
}
```

The exception:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Read is not supported on the main thread when
>   buffering is disabled.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You could try `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` or `Windows.Web.Syndication.SyndicationClient`

Comment: `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` works! Thanks!

Comment: @kiewic You should post that as an answer.